# Can't Logout From root domain

Tags: asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication

So I have an ASP.NET Web Forms Application with custom Forms Authentication. I basically just create a cookie that contains an encrypted user name and password and keep the session alive with that cookie. When a user logs out I add an expired cookie (cookie.Expires = Now) of the same name to the response. When I am on any actual page such as http://www.mydomain.com/default or http://www.mydomain.com/aboutus I have no problem logging out. BUT if the user happens to be on http://www.mydomain.com logout fails.

The cookie when an actual page contains the domain (www.mydomain.com) and the expired date. But when on www.mydomain.com that cookie contains no domain or expiration date.

Watching from Fiddler:
Logging out from root domain (http://www.mydomain.com) Fiddler says:

This response did not set any cookies.

Even though fiddler inspector displays my cookie by name-
Request sent 351 bytes of Cookie data:

ASP.NET_SessionId=tdohhekwzigkpuvqbphkzyxv; DEABE_ROBTFVAN=YYpYXpVjdkNEQwcPIhLrDkN4acbigcb9Ve9QusdfsdfdMCAYka981sdfsdfsdfXxl8eBXg==;

Logging out from any actual page (http://www.mydomain/aboutus)
Response sent 62 bytes of Cookie data:
    Set-Cookie: DEABE_ROBTFVAN=; expires=Sun, 06-Oct-2013 20:14:42 GMT; path=/__utmb=142232619.22.10.1381088759; __utmc=142232619;

My request from root domain when clicking logout looks like:
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mydomain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 682
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://www.mydomain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://www.mydomain.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=0d2rmdy1w5wsiontcrml12yw; DEABE_ROBTFVAN=YYpYXpVjdkNEQwcPIhLrDkN4acbigasdasdasdcb9Ve9QuMCAYka981Xxl8eBXg==; __utma=142232619.1494664078.1381091188.1381091188.1381094343.2; __utmb=142232619.3.10.1381094343; __utmc=142232619; __utmz=142232619.1381094343.2.2.utmcsr=mydomain.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=

My request when logging out from www.mydomain.com/about:
POST /About HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mydomain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 402
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://www.mydomain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://www.mydomain.com/About
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=0d2rmdy1w5wsiontcrml12yw; DEABE_ROBTFVAN=YYpYXpVjdkNEQwcPIhLrDkN4acbigcb9Ve9QuMCAYka981Xxl8eBXg==; __utma=142232619.1494664078.1381091188.1381091188.1381094343.2; __utmb=142232619.5.10.1381094343; __utmc=142232619; __utmz=142232619.1381094343.2.2.utmcsr=kazork.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/admin/user/UserSearch.aspx

my code:

```
 Public Sub Logout()

        GlobalFunctions.AddCookieToResponse(Nothing, Nothing, True)

        HttpContext.Current.Session("AP_CurrentUser") = Nothing
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon()

    End Sub

Public Shared Sub AddCookieToResponse(userName As String, password As String, Optional expireNow As Boolean = False)

    '====================================================================
    'Create top level domain cookie
    '====================================================================
    'Domain not being used currently, wanted to eliminate .mydomain I was seeing in the cookie
    Dim domain As String = GetDomain()

    Dim cookie As New HttpCookie(GlobalFunctions.GetCookieName())

    'If GlobalFunctions.HasData(domain) Then
    '    cookie.Domain = domain
    'End If

    If GlobalFunctions.HasData(userName) And GlobalFunctions.HasData(password) Then
        cookie.Value = GlobalFunctions.Encrypt(userName & ":" & password)
    End If

    If expireNow Then
        cookie.Expires = Now
    Else
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
    End If

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
    '====================================================================

End Sub

Public Shared Function GetCookieName() As String
    If GetCurrentWebsiteName() = Constants.WEBSITES.MyWebsite1 Then
        Return "DEABE_ROBTFVAN"
    Else
        Return "ABE_OPED_JDZRK"
    End If
End Function
```

**Response Traffic When it Works: (THERE ARE TWO RESPONSES WITH SUCCESSFUL LOGOUT**

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private,600
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /Default
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: DEABE_ROBTFVAN=; expires=Wed, 23-Oct-2013 05:57:45 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: OAUTHDEABE_ROBTFVAN=; domain=www.mydomain.com; expires=Wed, 23-Oct-2013 05:57:45 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 23 Oct 2013 05:57:45 GMT
Content-Length: 125

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/Default">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

**Repsonse 2 with successful logout**
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private,600
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 23 Oct 2013 06:23:03 GMT
Content-Length: 7710

��������`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$ؐ@������iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼��{���{���;�N'���?\fdl��J�ɞ!���?~|?"~��7N��O�

*** FIDDLER: RawDisplay truncated at 128 characters. Right-click to disable truncation. ***

**Response Traffic When logout at root domain doesn't work:**

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private,600
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 23 Oct 2013 06:12:25 GMT
Content-Length: 8274

��������`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$ؐ@������iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼��{���{���;�N'���?\fdl��J�ɞ!���?~|?"~��7N��O�

*** FIDDLER: RawDisplay truncated at 128 characters. Right-click to disable truncation. ***

Comment: Can you post the HTTP response traffic that you get in the following two situations?  (1) When you log out and it works, and (2) When you log out and it doesn't work.

Comment: Added, well there is something definitely wrong. I use this code for two domains, one allows log out from the root domain but the domain being used in my question fails to log out at root domain, same code, just different cookie name for each domain.

Comment: And the two cookie names you see here, DEABE_ROBTFVAN and OAUTHDEABE_ROBTFVAN are for the same domain, the cookies kill a regular session or an OAuth session respectively, whether one exists or not. I don't have any response/request information included for my other domain that works for logout at the root domain using the same library and code, I am just mentioning that this code works fine for another website which almost makes me think it is a DNS issue of some strangeness.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to set the expiration to a date in the past

```
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays( -1 );
```

If this doesn't help, verify that you don't set Path when you issue the cookie.

If this still doesn't help, use an http debugger, like fiddler, to verify what happens - you seem not sure whether the cookie doesn't get to the browser or the browser doesn't accept it but one of the two can be easily eliminated when you see the traffic with the debugger.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I DO NOT set Path and the cookie is included in the response. When the url is www.mydomain.com/default the cookie domain and expiration or set. But the cookie for www.mydomain.com contains no domain or expiration but it is the exact same code for both pages that creates the cookie and adds it to the response.

Comment: And how about the http debugger?

Comment: Added my Fiddler info, it is clear the cookie is in the response but it is not "mapped" or "detected" at the root domain level by the browser or Fiddle for that matter.

Comment: How does your "root domain level" request look like? (What server resource is called to log out?)

Comment: I added my requests when Logging out from the root domain compared to being on www.mydomain.com/about. I when I log out it is a javascript making a __postback to a Log out method in my code behind master page (ASP.NET). That log out implementation adds an expired cookie of the same name to the response, very straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have different cookies with the same name.  This can happen if the cookies are not all created the same way.  If you are not specifying the path then the cookies will be relative to the page.

Comment: No I am using the same cookie name. I do not specify the cookie domain, if that is what you mean by path. I have a another website that is using the exact same library that contains the cookie creation logic and do not have this issue logging out from the root domain.

Comment: I have added some of my code for creating the cookie and adding to the response to my question.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like the issue is with the cookies. The traffic you posted looks weird (or maybe I'm just not reading it correctly).

When you log out, do you `POST` to `/` and `/About`? That's what it says in the first part of your logs but I would normally expect it to go to `/Logout` or something like that.

Then, when the server responds, the successful version returns a 302 with a `Set-Cookie`. That's the bit that removes the cookie. The second response is just following the redirect from the 302.

When it fails, it returns a 200 without a `Set-Cookie` which makes me wonder if the server side Logout method was called at all.

Comment: It is called, the cookie is added to the Response, I Redirect to /Default after the Logout() method logic continues. The funky response seems to be Response.Redirect issue that is separate issue/bug from my main problem. It seems to be that the cookie just doesn't "map" itself to the root domain properly but I guess the cookie just isn't in the logout response at the root domain. I use ASP.NET to create the cookie and I feel like it is not creating the cookie correctly at the root domain

Comment: Have you confirmed that the Logout method is being called when the logout doesn't work through some other means other than the cookies? Do you have logging in your application or something like that?

Comment: What I mean by the last part of my answer is that there isn't a ``Set-Cookie`` header in the response you marked as "Response Traffic When logout at root domain doesn't work"

Comment: Well the Logout method gets called when I am on any webpage, I don't see why it wouldn't be called at the root domain. Especially since I use the same class library on another website and Logout works everywhere

Comment: Maybe that's true but we can't tell from the data you provided and the web traffic logs look weird. In your position, I would check, just for sanity.

Comment: I know the logout method is being called, that is not the issue, this line is being called HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)

Comment: Even though the corresponding ``Set-Cookie`` doesn't appear in your traffic logs...

Comment: That is correct, there is something going on with the root domain of this website only, like I said I use the same code for another website,the code is adding the cookie to the response, I think ASP.NET tries to add the cookie to the response but there is some kind of "mistake" when adding the cookie to the response with ASP.NET with this particular root domain, almost like it is a proxy/firewall/dns issue of some kind and ASP.NET fails to add the cookie to the response.